Cannot assign eloquent object on livewire property
I have a simple task on my livewire (v3) component to assign eloquent object like so :
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Users;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Traits\Swalable;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;
use Livewire\Attributes\Validate;

class Edit extends Component
{
    use Swalable;

    public $departments;
    public $sections;
    public $roles;
    
    public ?User $user;

    #[Validate('required|min:3', as:'Nama')]
    public $name;

    #[Validate('required|min:3|max:3', as:'Inisial')]
    public $initial;

    public $email;

    #[Validate('Required', as:'Role')]
    public $role;

    public $department;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->fill([
            'departments' => \App\Models\Department::all(),
            'sections' => \App\Models\Section::all(),
            'roles' => \App\Models\Role::all()
        ]);
    }

    #[On('edit-user')]
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $this->resetExcept('roles','sections');

        $this->user = \App\Models\User::with('sections')->find($id);

        $this->fill([
            'name' => $this->user->name,
            'initial' => $this->user->initial,
            'email' => $this->user->email,
            'role' => $this->user->role_id
        ]);
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate();

        $this->user->update($this->except(['email']));

        $this->toastSuccess('User berhasil diupdate.');

        $this->dispatch('user-updated');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.users.edit');
    }
}

Then render it on the view :
<x-modal name="edit" title="Edit Data User">
    <x-slot:body>
        @if (!is_null($user))
        <div class="relative overflow-x-auto">
            <form
                wire:submit="save"
                class="m-4 p-4">
                <div class="grid gap-2 grid-cols-2">
                    <x-forms.input type="text" label="Nama" model="name" />
                    <x-forms.input type="text" label="Inisial" model="initial" />
                    <x-forms.input type="email" label="Email" model="email" disabled/>
                    <x-forms.select label="Role" model="role">
                        <option></option>
                        @foreach ($roles as $role)
                            <option value="{{ $role->id }}" {{ $role->id === $user->role_id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $role->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </x-forms.select>
                    <x-forms.select label="Department" model="department" :multiple="true">
                        @foreach ($departments as $department)
                            @php
                                $assignedDepartments = collect($user->sections)->map(function ($arr) {
                                    return $arr['department_id'];
                                });

                            @endphp
                            <option value="{{ $department->id }}" {{ in_array($department->id, $assignedDepartments->toArray()) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $department->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </x-forms.select>
                    <x-forms.select label="Section" model="section" :multiple="true">
                        @foreach ($sections as $section)
                            @php
                                $assignedSections = collect($user->sections)->map(function ($arr) {
                                    return $arr['id'];
                                });

                            @endphp
                            <option value="{{ $section->id }}" {{ in_array($section->id, $assignedSections->toArray()) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $section->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </x-forms.select>
                </div>

                <div
                    wire:target="save"
                    wire:loading.remove>
                    <x-button type="submit" color="blue">Simpan</x-button>
                </div>
                
                <x-spinner target="save" />
            </form>
        </div>
        @endif
    </x-slot>
</x-modal>

select component :
@props(['label','model', 'width', 'multiple' => false])
@php
    $selectId = strtolower(str_replace(' ','',$label));
@endphp

<div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'me-4 mb-4 w-'.($width ?? 'full')]) }}>
    <label for="{{ $selectId }}" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">{{ $label }}</label>
    <select
        @if ($multiple)
            {{ $attributes->merge(['multiple' => $multiple]) }}
        @endif
        wire:model="{{ $model }}"
        id="{{ $selectId }}"
        class="blcok bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500">
        {{ $slot }}
    </select>

    @error($model) 
    <span><small class="text-sm text-red-600"> {{ $message }} </small></span>
    @enderror
</div>

The sections property can be rendered, however the departments property keep getting this error :

foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given

I already test using the tinker , the data is there :
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#5674
    all: [
      App\Models\Department {#6298
        id: 1,
        name: "JAI",
        created_at: "2024-04-19 21:37:27",
        updated_at: null,
      },
      App\Models\Department {#6299
        id: 2,
        name: "FATP",
        created_at: "2024-04-19 21:38:32",
        updated_at: null,
      },
    ],
}

How can I solve this ?
Update #1
I tried to pass it directly to the view like so :
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.users.edit', [
        'departments' => \App\Models\Department::all()
    ]);
}

And it worked, it's weird.
I'm Still wondering why it didn't work inside the mount() method

Can you show your forms.select?

Is that your entire file for livewire.users.edit?

@TUPKAP I updated it, please check

@Qirel No, I updated it, please check

Since the lists are not tied to any wire:model or similar, they are not returned from the frontend to the backend. Since mount() is executed only once at the beginning, the properties are no longer valued and, as they do not have a default value, they are NULL. You could use boot() instead of mount() however your solution (passing the data as view parameters) is more convenient.

@TUPKAP , Ok I will try the boot method, however it's weird that I also tried the $sections property and didn't get any problem,
they ($sections & $ departments) both not tied with any wire:model either

@TUPKAP that's simply not true. All public properties are available as variables in the view, and they get rehydrated on each request - regardless if you have them bound to wire:model or not

@owf I'm not seeing the full picture here. Are there any other files or components involved? Like the $user variable, I can't see it defined. What you have here should work from what I'm seeing..

@Qirel I updated the full livewire class, please check, and please note that i also render the edit.blade.php view inside another livewire component called index.blade.php

Is there by chance a mount() method in your Swalable trait?

@Qirel no there is only methods inside that Trait
